# Adding to a set of sets with a loop

Tags: java, loops, set

The output of the code below is [[3],[3],[3],[3]].
It seems to me that it should be [[0],[1],[2],[3]]
The set of sets seems to be retaining its size, but not its elements through the loop.

```
Set<Set<String>> mySetOfSets = new HashSet<Set<String>>();
mySetOfSets.clear();            

Set<String> numbers = new HashSet<String>(); 

for(int i=0; i<4 ; i++)
 {
    numbers.clear();
    String iAsString = String.valueOf(i);
    numbers.add(iAsString);
        mySetOfSets.add(numbers);                       
 }
   System.out.println( mySetOfSets);
```

Comment: Second one on the same day :) http://stackoverflow.com/q/17871203/335858

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're adding the same `Set<String> numbers` variable in the `Set<Set<String>> mySetOfSets`. You must create a new instance of the `Set<String> numbers` on each loop iteration.

```
for(int i=0; i<4 ; i++) {
    Set<String> numbers = new HashSet<String>(); 
    //rest of your code...
}
```

Before applying the proposed fix in your code, you were doing this:

1. Having a single `Set<String> numbers`.
2. Clearing its items.
3. Adding a new item into `numbers`.
4. Adding `numbers` into `Set<Set<String>> mySetOfSets`.
5. Going back to point 2.

By applying the proposed fix in your code, now you're doing this:

1. Creating a new instance of `Set<String> numbers` that will be different from the previous `Set<String>` instances.
2. Clearing its items (note that this should be removed since is a new `Set<String>` and there's no need to clear it).
3. Adding a new item into `numbers`.
4. Adding `numbers` into `Set<Set<String>> mySetOfSets`.
5. Going back to point 1.

Comment: Fantastic!  Can you explain why that fixed the problem though?  I guess I don't understand when variables should be defined inside or outside of a loop.

Comment: @user2623054 answer updated. Let me know if you need a better explanation on the subject.

Comment: I understand the difference in what is happening; but I don't understand why this subtle change would make a difference in the final results (i.e. the contents of mySetofSets).  Why is the new instance better?

Comment: @user2623054 Because in the first you were adding **the same object reference** to `Set<Set<String>> mySetOfSets`, so any changes in one of the elements would affect all the elements (since they are the same, even if they are in a different location inside `mySetOfSets`). In the second, you're adding **a different object reference** to `Set<Set<String>> mySetOfSets`, so any changes done to an element will affect only to this element.